# Executing very large command string from batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file containing set of commands.Each command string is over 9000 charecters,but windows 7 cmd limits the size to 8191 characters.Is there a way to overcome this limits ?

Answer (score 0):

Not without reducing the side of your string by means of variable names and folder paths etc.

Switch to powershell!

Comment: Excuse me. Is powershell capable of executing commands with parameter strings longer than 8191 characters? Could you post a link to such information? Thanks...